# When and why was zero right ascension defined to be at the vernal equinox?

Tags: history, celestial-mechanics, naked-eye, definition, earths-orbit

When (and why) was zero [right ascension](https://skyandtelescope.org/astronomy-resources/right-ascension-declination-celestial-coordinates/) defined to be at the vernal equinox?  Who established or defined this standard?

Comment: You may enjoy [The Historical Development of Celestial Co-ordinate Systems](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1942PASP...54...77W/0000077.000.html). I'm still reading this article, but it makes sense for there to be a common origin for ecliptic longitude and right ascension. And an equinox point is a natural origin for ecliptic longitude.